# Draw bounding boxding box around whole block of text In image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I have the image, i have removed the noise (dots in the background) and, I want to draw a bounding box around the block of text In image  how can I do it using python OpenCV

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Noise Removed Image:

[image: Noise Removed Image]

Here is the code used to remove noise in background Where i can change to save images with bounding boxes around the text

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
def remove_dots(image_path,outdir):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)

    # Create horizontal kernel then dilate to connect text contours
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

    # Find contours and filter out noise using contour approximation and area filtering
    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        area = w * h
        ar = w / float(h)
        if area > 1200 and area < 50000 and ar <8:
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
    # Bitwise-and input image and mask to get result
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
    result[mask==0] = (255,255,255) # Color background white


    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(outdir,os.path.basename(image_path)),result)
    
for jpgfile in glob.glob(r'C:\custom\TableDetectionWork\text_detection_dataset/*'):
    print(jpgfile)
    remove_dots(jpgfile,r'C:\custom\TableDetectionWork\textdetect/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using a horizontal morphology filter to merge the letters in a mask image. Then find the contours. Then get the bounding boxes.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("john.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply horizontal morphology close
kernel = np.ones((5 ,191), np.uint8)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# draw contours
result = img.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    # get bounding boxes
    pad = 10
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x-pad, y-pad), (x+w+pad, y+h+pad), (0, 0, 255), 4)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("john_bbox.png",result)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Morphology Closed Image:

[image]

Bounding Boxes Image:

[image]

Comment: I have gone through this approach but I want the same thing in the above code where I can change that?

Comment: I do not understand. What is wrong with your code and why can you not just do this in your code. You draw the contour. But you should be drawing the bounding box. Other than that, I do not see what is wrong in your code. Please explain further.

Comment: In my code i try to save the images by placing cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 3) after  cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1), but it doesnot work. no images is saving with bounding boxes

Comment: Use cv2.imshow() on your mask and result images to see that they look as expected. Use imshow() at each step and make sure each one produces what you expect.

Comment: Count how many contours are kept by your if condition. Perhaps you are throwing out all of them.

Comment: I have tried that but it's doesn't work. Can you please check it?

Comment: You are drawing white filled contours for each letter, not the words and not the bounding boxes. So of course you will just get your letters showing. What is it that you want? If you want bounding boxes, then draw rectangles not contours and draw outlines and not filled contours.  If you want bounding boxes around words and not letters, then use a long horizontal morphology kernel as in my example.

Comment: So where can i change in my code to apply horizontal morphology  kernal?

Comment: You have morphology already. Just make the kernel much wider. Look at my example for the kernel size. Rather than dilate, use a close. Then simply draw the bounding boxes of the contours that you filter on a copy of the input image. If you want it on your filtered result, then you would need to reprocess your result with the morphology close, then do the contours on that to get the words and get their bounding boxes and draw the rectangles for the bounding boxes.

Comment: Can you please change the code where I would change which will work for me and the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the core of your code modified to do what you want in Python/OpenCV. It is just adding my code to the end of your code.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
    
image = cv2.imread("john.jpg")
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)

# Create horizontal kernel then dilate to connect text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours and filter out noise using contour approximation and area filtering
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = w * h
    ar = w / float(h)
    if area > 1200 and area < 50000 and ar <8:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        
# Bitwise-and input image and mask to get result
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255) # Color background white

# NEW CODE HERE TO END _____________________________________________________________
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(gray2, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh2 = 255 - thresh2
kernel = np.ones((5 ,191), np.uint8)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# draw contours
result2 = result.copy()
for cntr in contours:
    # get bounding boxes
    pad = 10
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(result2, (x-pad, y-pad), (x+w+pad, y+h+pad), (0, 0, 255), 4)

cv2.imwrite("john_bboxes.jpg", result2)

cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
cv2.imshow("thresh",thresh)
cv2.imshow("dilate",dilate)
cv2.imshow("result",result)
cv2.imshow("gray2",gray2)
cv2.imshow("thresh2",thresh2)
cv2.imshow("close",close)
cv2.imshow("result2",result2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Bounding Boxes on Your Result:

[image]